# Can you transfer characters from gta 5 on the ps4 to another ps4 account

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, ps4

I want to transfer my character from one gamertag on the ps4 to another new gamertag on the same console, is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I transfer my GTA 5 character to my new Xbox One from my friend's Xbox One?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/231257/can-i-transfer-my-gta-5-character-to-my-new-xbox-one-from-my-friends-xbox-one)

Comment: Definetly atleast related to the Xbox version of the question, but considering that it is not a mechanic or feature specific to the playstation console, I think they should just be merged into the one "can I transfer my character to another user account" question

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is not possible, no. Your progress is irrevocably locked to the specific gamertag you made that progress on, and can not be transferred to another gamertag, like you would be able to with just transfering to another console.

Quoting from [Rockstar Support](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC):

> "When transferring from PlayStation3 to PlayStation4, you must use the same PSN ID. A new PSN ID on PlayStation4 cannot be transferred to from a different PSN ID on PlayStation3 since your characters progress is tied to the PSN account."

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just call rockstar support and tell thim you want to switch a character to the other profile and they will take care of it

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can actually, you need to transfer your character to Xbox, then from the Xbox you transfer back to your new ps4 account

Comment: AFAIK, you can not transfer to an xbox at all, from a playstation 4. Perhaps you should go into more detail.