# Can I transfer my GTA 5 character to my new Xbox One from my friend's Xbox One?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I transferred my level 253 GTA 5 character to my friends Xbox one. Now I got an Xbox One of my own, so I've bought GTA 5.

Can I transfer this character to my Xbox one?

Answer (score 1):

You can't move it to your account. But you can try to login to his XBL account and play on that account.